# how to show error message in react js when http request send?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

could you please tell me how to show error message in react js when http request send ?

I make a service in the nodejs where I am sending `400` status with `error message` . I want to show this error message on `frontend`.

```
app.get('/a',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(400).send({message:" some reason error message"})
})
```

Now I want to show this error message on frontend .`on catch I will not get this message`.

```
try {
            const r = await axios.get('http://localhost:3002/a');
} catch (e) {
            console.log('===============================================')
            console.log(e)
            console.log(e.data)
            hideLoading();
            setErrorMessage(e.message);
            showErrorPopUp();
        }
```

`on catch` i will not get this message.getting on `stack of error
[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's better to respond with a JSON in this particular case from the server:

```
app.get('/a',(req,res) => {
    res.status(400).json({message:"some reason error message"})
})
```

So in the client, you can read from `error.response` easily

```
try {
  const r = await axios.get('http://localhost:3002/a');
} catch (e) {
  if (e.response && e.response.data) {
    console.log(e.response.data.message) // some reason error message
  }
}
```

Read more about handling caught errors in axios [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

Answer (score 0):

That's a very subjective question. You might need to use some middleware to handle async actions in a better way like redux-saga or redux-thunk.

The approach would be define a error state in your store. And, when you get an error update the state, dispatching an action.

And, in your component (container), you need to have an observer to get the updated error state.

```
try {
  const r = await axios.get('http://localhost:3002/a');
} catch (e) {
  if (e.response && e.response.data) {
    // Dispatch an action here
    console.log(e.response.data.message) // some reason error message
  }
}
```

For reference, there is a very basic and good tutorial by Dan.
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-displaying-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

Axios have validateStatus in request-config where you can whitelist your status

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

> // `validateStatus` defines whether to resolve or reject the promise
>   for a given   // HTTP response status code. If `validateStatus`
>   returns `true` (or is set to `null`   // or `undefined`), the promise
>   will be resolved; otherwise, the promise will be   // rejected.

````
axios
  .get("<URL>",{validateStatus: function (status) {
    return (status >= 200 && status < 300) || status==400;
  }})
  .then(function(response) {
    // handle success;
  })
  .catch(function(response) {
    // handle error
  })
  .finally(function(error) {
    // always executed
  }); ```
````