# how to access 403's response statusText in axios [REACT , EXPRESS,NODE JS ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

so in my component I have this register function which calls my api and in the api I check if the email exists or not and depending on that a send appropriate status with statusText
here is the api call handler in my express app :

```
router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{
    const {email,password,firstname,lastname}=  req.body
    try {
        const passHash=await bcrypt.hash(password,1);
        if(passHash == undefined) throw new Error('erro hassing password'); 
        
        const checkEmailExistsPromise= await UserModel.findOne({email:email})
        if( checkEmailExistsPromise !== null) throw new Error('EMAIL')

        res.statusMessage = "user registerd ";
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (error) {
        if(error.message="EMAIL"){
             res.statusMessage='email already used';
             res.sendStatus(403)
            }
            console.log(error)
    }
})
```

and here is my register function thjat I have in my react component

```
    const register=async (e)=>{
         e.preventDefault()
         if(!validate()) return ; 
         try {
             const regsterUserPromise= await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/register',{...userInfo})
             //when its a 200 status ts easy 
             console.log(regsterUserPromise.statusText)
         } catch (error) {
             //I want to get the status text of that 403 response 
             console.log(error)
         }
    }
```

```
now all I'm getting is 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Rfb.png
```

Comment: check fields of your `error` object, there should be something like "responseText" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) which contain unparsed response body

Comment: In catch block of reactjs . You will receive response with status code 403. So you have to handle here itself

Comment: I know that people's opinions about this differ, but my approach would be to reserve http errors for actual http connection errors and use status 200 for everything else, including application logic errors. Just send back a reply that indicates that the email doesn't exist, and you can easily read the message in the try block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show error message in react js when http request send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583761/how-to-show-error-message-in-react-js-when-http-request-send)

Comment: @ChrisG your answer actually makes a lot of sense and its convenient

Comment: @ChrisG yes it kinda did but I had to modify to ```error.response.statusText ``` response is what I was messing , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

so all I had to do to access the status Text is is `error.response.statusText` in my catch block

Comment: But you already had `console.log(error)` in there..., didn't you see the text?

Comment: it actually showed   POST ... 403 (Not Found) as a string